# cxf client configuration issue

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I have a jax-ws client configured via spring to hit a remote https web service. The first time I call my client to talk to the server the whole communication is successful. The second time I call my service to talk to the remote web service, I see the outbound soap message in my log but then I get javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message and Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException.  If I manually copy and paste the outbound soap message to soap-ui  - I get a response from the service quickly and I know the soap message is valid/the server is responding. If I restart my app the first call to the remote web service works again but subsequent calls fail. I am thinking perhaps this is a configuration issue on my part? my client is very basic and looks like this:

```
    <jaxws:client id="xxClient" 
       serviceClass="com.fake.{path to web service}"
       address="https address here">

      <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wss4jOut"/>
      </jaxws:outInterceptors>

    </jaxws:client>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being non-reproducible on test/dev servers. something must have been off with my local machine. I was using cxf minimal bundle 2.5.2.